# Invoke animation each time i open the screen of my react native application

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm using react native animatable to add animation to my app screens.
I've added bottom tab navigation and i want to make animation each time i click the tab icon to open the screen.
My problem is that the animation is launched only one time

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Animatable.View animation="fadeInUpBig" duraton="1500">
      <Text> Accueil </Text>
    </Animatable.View>
  </View>
```

Comment: can you try this attribute `iterationCount="infinite"`

Comment: that create an infinite loop of animation

Comment: I think a see, what you want to implement you need to reset tabBar each time you press it like this you have new render. React-navigation v4 you do that like this `resetOnBlur={true}`

Comment: i'm using react navigation 5

Comment: I dont know a lot about v5 sorry. Another way could be `navigation.addListner('willFocus',()=>{this.forceUpdate()}`